# What buttons have changed labels from fckeditor to ckeditor 4?

Tags: ckeditor

It appears that some of the button names have been changed in ckeditor version 4.

Is there a complete list of these changes?

There is a partial list [here](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/upgrading-fckeditor-to-ckeditor).

Comment: There might be, but Stack Overflow is arguably not the right place to ask about it. I'd check out http://ckeditor.com/forums

Comment: I suppose @Pekka웃,  but it would be nice to find the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that names haven't been changed. If something is not working check if plugin you need is included in your build (most likely it is a standard preset) and if not:

- [download](http://ckeditor.com/download) a full preset (which in fact does not include all plugins too, but most of them) or
- add required plugins to your custom [CKEditor build](http://ckeditor.com/builder).
- [**EDIT**] another useful resource is the toolbar sample shipped with CKEditor package. E.g. [here](http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.1.1/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html)'s one for a standard package.

Comment: I have found (by digging in the code) that a number of the labels for the buttons have changed. StrikeThrough is now Strike, for instance.

Comment: Nope - basic styles button names haven't been changed since 2009 - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blame/master/plugins/basicstyles/plugin.js#L88-L93. Are we talking about the same thing? :D PS. I added another link to my answer.

Comment: Ah!.  I'm sorry, we've upgraded from fckeditor to ckeditor.  The changes were done then rather than between 3 and 4.  http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/upgrading-fckeditor-to-ckeditor

Comment: Hehe :) I'm glad you found a solution. And you're right that if something changed, then most likely between FCK and CKE3. CKE4 is pretty compatible with CKE3.